# Is the 'electrostatics' condition impossible for a point charge existing in space with conductivity?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electrical-resistance, conductors

It is a known equation that:

$$ \vec{j} = \sigma \vec{E}$$

Where $\vec{j}$ is current per area density, $ \vec{E}$ is the electric field and $\sigma$ is the conductivity.

Consider the set up of having a point charge of $+q$ at the origin(*) in a space filled with a conducting medium of conductivity $\rho$, it will cause an electric field distance $r$ from origin as:

$$ E = \frac{kq}{r^2} \hat{r}$$

Plugging this into current density formula:

$$ \vec{J} = \sigma \frac{kq}{r^2} \hat{r}$$

If we integrate this over a sphere of radius $r$ center at origin:

$$ I =\frac{ \sigma kq }{r^2} \int dS= 4 \pi \sigma kq $$

Now, this gives us an equation relating the charge inside surface and current inside, now if we were to say:

$$ I =- \frac{dq}{dt} = 4 \sigma \pi  k q$$

Then we find that:

$$ q = q_o e^{-4 \sigma \pi kt}$$

This seems a strange result for me, this means as $ t \to \infty$ the point charge inside the surface drops to zero. So, where did this charge disappear too? There was no external field to make it move. A simple case if we are in a space with $\sigma=0$, then it is easy to see that $q_o$ is constant, but what if we have a medium with finite $\sigma$?

It may be also noted that this isn't an issue if we have a conducting surface because the charge induced on the surface will have field such that field of charge contained inside is cancelled. Therefore, eventually there will be zero current flow.

---

Came as an after thought of revisiting [this irodov question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548271/resistance-between-metal-balls-in-an-infinite-homogeneous-conducting-medium)

*: I'm not quite sure what would happen if I let it be free to move but let's say it's fixed in place origin.

Comment: Why are you using an equation for a current inside a conductor ($j = \sigma E$) together with the equation for the electric field of a point charge in vacuum? What physical situation is this supposed to model?

Comment: @ACuriousMind See the solution to this problem [here](https://www.sarthaks.com/214000/metal-balls-same-radius-located-homogeneous-poorly-conducting-medium-with-resistivity) , in it we assume charges and apply ohm's law in the form with conductivity

Comment: 1. That question explicity stipulates that we are inside a "homogeneous poorly conducting medium". Yours doesn't even mention a medium. 2. If we are in a medium with movable charges, then the $q$ (fixed charge at origin) in your equation for $I$ is *not* the same $q$ as in $I = \dot{q}$, since there the $q$ is the movable charges in the conducting medium, so your differential equation is just wrong (and your charge is not fixed). Again, what physical situation are we actually modelling here?

Comment: I've added in the first point, so how would I fix the differential equation? For the last point, I didn't really a 'physical situation' in mind which is similar to the set up (that I know of) because I'm trying to understand the equations in physics using example scenarios. @ACuriousMind

Comment: That may be the fundamental problem here - you're essentially just putting together two random equations because they look like they fit together (because both have a charge called $q$), but you never stopped to think that the charge $q$ in $I = \frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}$ inside a conductor is completely different from the stationary charge $q$ in the el. field of a point charge. I don't think you can really "fix" this, your question is simply ill-defined because you just looked at the symbols in the equations instead of thinking about the physical situation they model

Comment: So, if my question is ill defined, how does the solution to the question I have linked make sense? ( This q was made in an attempt to understand it's solution a bit more actually) @ACuriousMind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121075/discussion-between-buraian-and-acuriousmind).

Answer (score 2):

The current flowing out through the surface is *minus* the rate of change inside:  $$
I = -dq/dt.
$$
This leads to exponential decay, not exponential growth:
$$
q = q_0 e^{-4 \pi k \sigma t} = q_0 e^{-t/\tau}
$$
with $\tau = 1/ 4 \pi \sigma k = \epsilon_0/\sigma$.

What this is telling you is that if you implant a point charge inside a conducting medium, it will cause the charge carriers in the conductor to flow towards it in such a way to eventually cancel it out.  In practice, the time scale on which this occurs is $\tau = \epsilon_0/\sigma$;  and we can see that the better the conductor is, the quicker this cancellation occurs.

Comment: Does this mean whole charge disappears after time -> infinity? How is this possible? I'll modify the question

Comment: @Buraian:  see my edit.

Comment: So, the electrostqatic case is not possible when we have medium with conductivity?

Comment: @Buraian: as I have already told you in my answer, negative charges from the surface will flow to the center where the positive charge is, and neutralize it. The positive charges that remain at the surface are virtually equivalent to the former center charge, as if the center charge was distributed over the surface. Since the charge separation compensates the original E-field, the charge separation exponentially comes to an end, as shown by Michael.

Comment: @Buraian:  I wouldn't make a statement quite as broad as that;  there are some situations where you can apply [electrostatic techniques in conductive media](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/619801/why-is-electric-field-across-a-resistor-constant-or-voltage-gradient-linear/).  But in general, if you have $\rho \neq 0$ in a uniform conductive medium, then this implies $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} \neq 0 \Rightarrow \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J} \neq 0 \Rightarrow \partial \rho /\partial t \neq 0$.  In other words, non-zero charge distributions in uniform conductive media cannot be static.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have assumed the point charge $q$ to be constant, right? Then the differential equation that leads to the exponential cannot be right. What really happens is that due to universal charge neutrality there has to be a charge $q^\prime=-q$ somewhere. The electric fields of $q$ and $q^\prime$ superpose to a resulting field $\vec E^\prime$, and consequently, the current due to Ohm's law will also be proportional to that (different) electric field.

How that field looks, depends on your initial conditions. If the countercharge $q^\prime$ is very close to $q$, their electric fields will almost cancel. For example, in a hydrogen atom the ground state is spherically symmetric, so the electric fields of nucleus and electron will even cancel exactly. So you will not have any current "outside the atom" (actually the outside is not exactly defined because the electron's wave function extends to infinity, but the distance where it has become almost zero is of course very small).

But if you really have a countercharge that is a larger distance apart from your central charge $q$, the current being calculated by Ohm's law will be directed in such a way as to cancel the charge separation in the end. For example if the countercharge is on the surface of the conductor, it will flow towards the center charge. However, if the countercharge is constrained to some geometry outside the conductor, it cannot flow through the conductor. Instead, opposite charges from the surface of the conductor will flow to the center, to the effect that the former charge in the center becomes virtually distributed over the surface of the conductor.

The math details are fairly comprehensive, depending on the boundary conditions, and so cannot be answered in the context of this question. There are certain techniques in electrostatics for determining the final state, like the method of [image charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges).

Comment: " I  think you have assumed the point charge q to be constant, right?" No, I just assumed that a pont charge being there as the initial set up

Comment: Then you should present your assumptions because with just what you have stated, the problem is ill-defined. Charge neutrality is a fact. Conservation of charge also. You do not take this into account for your problem definition.

Comment: I mean I think this answer agrees with other answers in the second part but first part of your answer (that my differential equation is wrong) contradicts the micheal's answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec j=\sigma\vec E$ is a relation between a conduction current for many electrons and the *external* electric field that drives their motion *in a conductor*.  In particular the expression for $\sigma$ includes (implicitly) the relaxation time, which can be understood as an average time between collisions with a lattice.

Thus the expression does not apply to (and does not represent)the electric field generated by a freely moving point charge: rather it is the response of the charges to an external field.

In addition, the sign of your $I$ is wrong since it represents charges *leaving* the inside of the surface.  With the negative sign, and inserting factors of $\sigma$ etc, one eventually gets a charge density
$$
\rho(t)\sim \rho_0 e^{-\sigma t/\epsilon}. \tag{1}
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the permittivity of the material.  The expression (1) can be used to show that, in a conductor, the charge density inside the conductor, when it is plunged into an external field, rapidly goes to $0$: this is a somewhat hand-wavy argument to explain the absence of electric fields in ideal conductors: $\rho(t)\to 0$ very quickly since $\sigma\to\infty$.

Comment: The point charge in the center *does* cause an external field to the conductor.

Comment: @oliver I do not quite understand your comment but then again the question isn’t very clear.  Bottom line is $\vec j=\sigma\vec E$ refers to the current in the conductor induced by an external field, so if you integrate around the origin (where the point charge is) you should not be using $\vec j=\sigma\vec E$ which applies inside a material.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: you can perfectly integrate over a sphere close to the origin. Why shouldn't you. The current is ignorant to what is inside or outside, it just defines what goes through an arbitrary surface.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: apparently, now I don't understand... :-) I thought it was clear from the mention of "point charge" that, initially, there was only an external Coulomb field. From there, the superposition principle takes over, doesn't it?

Comment: I am afraid, I don't know what you think is the problem. The point charge causes an external field, the conductor responds to that by moving charges. That's bread and butter business for Ohm's law, isn't it. There might be some ramifications on the solid-state physics level, there you probably know more than me, but basically Ohm's law is true, I hope we agree.

Comment: What I don't get is, why you seem to think that the point charge "inside" the conductor does not generate an external field for the conductor. I mean, yes, if the movement of the point charge itself was part of the problem statement, then I would agree that it gets more complicated. But I understood from the question that the point charge is fixed in the middle, so it's equation of motion does not have to be solved.

Comment: Check. Let's settle it, I think you know the physics as well or better than me. No reason to jerk around communication problems. ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121074/discussion-between-zerothehero-and-oliver).